# What are the terms in a percentage calculation called?

Tags: mathematics, percentages

Say you want to calculate how many percent 50 of 200 is:

```
50 / 200 = 0.25 = 25%
```

What do you call the individual pieces (50, 200, 0.25 and 25%) of this calculation?

Are the following terms (based on a direct translation [from German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prozent#Begriffe)) appropriate?

- *Base value* for 200 (from "Grundwert")
- *Percent value* for 50 (from "Prozentwert")
- *Ratio* for 0.25 (from "Verhältnis")
- *Percentage* for 25% (from "Prozentsatz")

Comment: *Ratio* and *percentage* are appropriate. The others are not.

Comment: The terms used for the first two are normally context specific. For the 200, 'population' is a general term. For the 50, 'instances', 'hits', 'occurrences', or "counts". And using 'ratio' for 0.25 is a bit sloppy for formal situations. 50:150 is a ratio that evaluates to 0.25 (or 0.333, it depends - 50 apples and 150 oranges or 50 tooth drive gear and 150 tooth follower gear). 2:3:8:20 is a ratio of four things, perhaps paint pigments - what does that evaluate to? If you choose to express a ratio of two things as a fraction, just use the terms for fractions - numerator and denominator.

Comment: @Phil Sweet 'Corresponds to' rather than 'evaluates to': a ratio is a static comparison between two elements whereas a quotient is the single-element result of a binary operation. Evaluation in maths demands a working out.

Comment: Regarding 50 / 200 as a single element (a rational number), 50 is the numerator and 200 the denominator of the fraction. Regarding it as a variant of 50 ÷ 200, 50 is the dividend and 200 the divisor. // 200 is certainly the base (figure), but '50 out of 200' is just about the only way to describe the 50 in these terms. // 25% and 0.25 are the percentage equivalent and decimal equivalent of the common fraction 50/200 (= 1/4 in simplest form).

Comment: In my job as an analyst, we would call 50 the numerator and 200 the denominator. As in saying 50 divided by 200.

Answer (score 2):

Preserving [Edwin's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/394422/what-are-the-terms-in-a-percentage-calculation-called#comment933621_394422):

> Regarding 50 / 200 as a single element (a rational number), 50 is the numerator and 200 the denominator of the fraction.
>
> Regarding it as a variant of 50 ÷ 200, 50 is the dividend and 200 the divisor.
>
> 200 is certainly the base (figure), but '50 out of 200' is just about the only way to describe the 50 in these terms.
>
> 25% and 0.25 are the percentage equivalent and decimal equivalent of the common fraction 50/200 (= 1/4 in simplest form).

<sub>[Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) is a retired maths teacher with a degree in chemistry.</sub>

Comment: Other terms would be part/whole for 50/200, proportion for .25.